# hierarchy of pages in breadcrumbs

Tags: wordpress

I'm creating a website in Wordpress and using plugin of Yoast SEO. It exists and creates the breadcrumbs and works perfectly in the hierarchy of posts, but not in the page hierarchy. For example...

I have a page called "page one" and a second page called "page two" which is the daughter of "page one".

The two page breadcrumbs looks like this:

```
"Home > Page Two",
```

but I need it to appear like this:

```
"Home > Page One > Page Two"...
```

How do I change breadcrumbs to appear the way I need? I did not find anything related to it even in settings.

Thanks.

Comment: what is the url of  Page Two?

Comment: url of page two is "site/page-one/page-two" @vrajesh

Answer (score 2):

I found a very usefull filter (**wpseo_breadcrumb_links**) in this file **/wordpress-seo/frontend/class-breadcrumbs.php** and i hope to solve your problem.

```
add_filter( 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links', 'wpseo_breadcrumb_links_fn' );
function wpseo_breadcrumb_links_fn( $links ) {
    global $post;

    // apply only on pages
    if ( is_page() ) {
        $post_parent = $post->post_parent;

        // get all parent posts
        while ( $post_parent != 0 ) { 
            $post_aux = get_post( $post_parent );
            $post_parents[] = array(
                'text' => $post_aux->post_title,
                'url' => get_permalink( $post_aux->ID )
            );
            $post_parent = $post_aux->post_parent;
        }

        // reverse array items
        $post_parents = count( $post_parents ) > 1 ? array_reverse( $post_parents ) : $post_parents;

        // add $post_parents in  $links
        array_splice( $links, 1, -2, $post_parents );
    }

    return $links;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Marcos! Simple code, it works, perfect!